# Use Jersey Filter in Spring Boot Jersey

Tags: spring-boot, filter, jersey

I have a Jersey rest API which we are planning to migrate to Spring boot.

I have a filter that implements `ContainerRequestFilter` and had `@Provider` annotation in the filter. I registered the filter in `ResourceConfig`. But still i don't see the filter executing.

However I do get a warning message:-
A provider "My Filter class" registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider interfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuration problems the provider "My Filter class" will be ignored.

I wanted to use jersey as servlet so changing the jersey to behave as filter is not working for my app.

Can someone help me on this?

Here is my code

Jersey filter

```
@Provider
public class CustomJerseyLoggingFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest request) { }

    @Override
    public ContainerResponse filter(ContainerRequest request, ContainerResponse response) { }
}

@Component
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyConfig() {
         register(CustomJerseyLoggingFilter.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code.

Comment: U mean to say , along with migrating to Spring Boot u want to keep the ContainerRequestFilter also  and before reaching the Spring Boot Controller it should intercept the Filter first ?

Comment: @SubhasishSahu - Yes, you are correct

Answer (score 4):

You're implementing the wrong `ContainerRequestFilter`. The one you are using is from Jersey 1.x. I don't know why you even have Jersey 1.x jars in your project. The `ContainerRequestFilter` (for 2.x) that you should be implementing is

> [`javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html)
>   [`javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerResponseFilter.html)

Comment: Yes, this fixed this issue. I changed the filter and it is working now. Thanks a lot for taking your time to looking into this.

Comment: @Deepa please select it as the answer then.